# Is ARAM Champion Select Truly Random?

Tags: league-of-legends

I get the feeling that ARAM isn't truly random. For one, it seems that free champs are present in games more often than others, and pretty often I go through streaks of rolling the same champion. Now I suppose, these could be statistical anomalies and the free champs probably have high likelihood due to being available to all, but I'm curious if Riot has said anything about this.

To provide some quasi-data, I've played about 500 ARAMs and I own about 25 champions and there are two or three that only rarely get rolled. Now this is probably a biased recounting, but I can't help but wonder.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it is really random. You will see free champions more often because they're the only champions that *everyone* owns.

Random is just that: random. Humans attempt to find patterns where there are none, and wind up perceiving that maybe the randomness isn't *really* random. They're wrong.

Comment: Sure, but I must point out that Riot goes to great lengths to balance things in the other game modes. So it doesn't seem like a great leap to think that they would do something like that in ARAM chapion select.

Comment: @maxywb The whole point of ARAM is mayhem. Trying to balance it is futile.

Comment: Oh for sure, that's why I play it so much ;). But I admit this is probably just wishful thinking on my part. Most games are so horrible one-sided...

Comment: I would only add that its not truly random as you cant have duplicate champions :) the "set" of possible champions shrinks each "choice" the system makes

Comment: It's truely random by that logic, though I don't like the fact that you're able to reroll or swap champions with other people, that makes it not so random imo. But yeah, they are random when first picked.

Comment: I have gotten the same champion 3 times in a row, it is really annoying specially when you have 80+

Comment: @Paralytic Annoying, yes. Random, also yes :P

Answer (score 1):

I dont think so i got all champions, i play only in aram  with friend, and we establish  there is a pool of 20 champs that came often (may 2 of my mates got them all  too, and  2 last  all most) and this pool  stay  the same approximatly 3 or 4 day the same and change a little.
Even if there is no "true" random 1/6 of all champions came about 60% of the time ... (60% because 2 got some champions who  were not in the actual pool)

Comment: Unless you have some scientific method that you used to come to this conclusion, you're incorrect. ARAM will always draw a random champ from your champ pool. The only limitations are that there can be no duplicates across teams (meaning that "popular" champs are more likely to show up) and that you can't draw a champ that you don't own. Once you've played enough and gotten to a high enough ARAM MMR, you might start seeing "ARAM only accounts" (accounts that only play ARAM and only buy champions that are good in ARAM) which skews the randomness, but that's usually not the case.

Comment: @S.Alfano: Humans have strong tendencies toward confirmation bias, meaning that if they have an opinion, they'll accept any evidence that supports that opinion while ignoring evidence against it. I've had streaks of ARAM where I got the same champion 3 times in a row (I own about 2/3 of all champs), but that does not makes champ select any less random. If you can prove with documentation showing which champions you and your friends get over the course of a significant amount of games (at least 100, preferably more) that it isn't random, you should let Riot know since that sounds like a bug.

Answer (score 1):

True Random? No.
Pseudo Random? Yes

It will be so random a Computer could do without other Tools. So the Core Answer: Yes the Hero Selection is Random and no Pre-Defined Set Of Heros or Algorithms which choose them for you.
But i don't think it will be True Random.

Some Links for the meaning of True Random.

- https://boallen.com/random-numbers.html
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation#.22True.22_vs._pseudo-random_numbers)

Comment: Though you're technically correct, I don't think the distinction between "true random" and "pseudo random" is all that important for the end user - in most cases, it looks the same.